# Return value of Single emitter Rx Java

Tags: java, kotlin, observable, rx-java2

How do I return a value from a Single observable in Rx Java

```
fun fetchRunResult() : Single<Boolean>{
   return Single.just(false)
}

fun canRun() : Boolean {
   return person.fetchRunResult() // get boolean instead of Single
}
```

Comment: did you mean calling `.blockingGet()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting between Reactive and Non-Reactive world is done via: blocking calls or subscribe

> Why use reactive?

- compose async event-streams without callback-hell
- design system as streams

> Convert Reactive-Type to Non-Reactive-Type: Blocking

```
fun canRun() : Boolean {
    return person.fetchRunResult().blockingGet()
}
```

With this method, you could just block the calling-thread, until a value is value is available.

> What is the Problem with blocking the calling thread?

- value may never arrive, therefore one thread is blocked forever
- if the blocked thread is an ui-loop, your UI will be frozen, because the thread is waiting blocked on a CountDownLatch (implementation-detail)

> Should I convert between Reactive and Non-Reactive type?

I would suggest to only use it with caution. Either you are aware, that the source is sync, or you now, that a value is already available. Therefore #blockingGet would not block the calling-thread

> What are the alternatives, when the source is async?

Model your stream and use #subscribe within a lifecycle handeled container. For example an Activity provides lifecycle methods. When using a subscription, the calling/ subscribing thread will not be blocked. You will get a callback every time, when a new value is available. The only thing to notice here is to cleanup your resources as in Disposable, because not doing so could lead to leaks with reactive types.

> Summary:

- if your data is async, your API should reflect that and not switch between reactive <-> non-reactive
- do not use blockingGet likely, because this could lead to a thread, which is blocked permanently

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful explanation. My call is asynchronous. It makes sense for me to subscribe and listen to those changes. I am calling this method on app start what is the right time to clear the disposable in this case ?

Comment: @luckysing_noobster, I would say it depends on your use-case, whether you have a service, activity or fragment. On an Activity I would probably use #onStop ( https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle ). It really depends on your use-case.

Comment: Thanks! What if I just want to emit the boolean value only once during app start. Is there a way without using disposable. This is a flag that tells me when to turn on/off a feature . After that, I don't have any use case of calling this method again.